# PHP not mailing any form data

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox, ternary

[Edit - added a complete form snippet] In my html - I have a single checkbox - which looks like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="contact-form row" id="feedbacks" method="POST" action="feedback.php">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <label for="full_name"></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name and surname" name="full_name" id="full_name">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="">
      <label for="feedback_email"></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email address" name="feedback_email" id="feedback_email">
    </fieldset>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label class="c-input c-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="subbed" id="subbed">
        <span class="c-indicator"></span>
        <span class="text-muted m-l-1">subscribe to <abbr class="msa"></abbr> notifcation service.</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="message"></label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="9" placeholder="Your message here.." name="message" id="message"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="row m-t-1">
      <fieldset class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" name="submit" type="submit" id="send_feedback">Send <i class="ion-android-arrow-forward"></i>
        </button>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subscribed" id="subscribed" value="sub_me">
```

In my PHP, I've created a variable `$subscribe` which links to the `subscribed` checkbox.

The PHP is supposed to send an email of `"I would not like to recieve news emails"` when the checkbox is left alone. To achieve this I have opted to use the following ternary inside the PHP form validation code:

[Edit - Supplying all the PHP]

```
<?php
    $value = '';
    $error = "";
    $error_message = "";
    $info = "";
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        $subscribe = 'Would ' . (isset($_POST['subbed']) && $_POST['subscribed'] == 'sub_me' ? 'like to ' : 'not like to ') . 'receive news emails.';
        $admin_email = "myemail_address@gmail.com";
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: <noreply@domain.ac.za>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $feedback_email . "\r\n";
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
        $feedback_email = $_POST['feedback_email'];
        $feedback = $_POST['message'];
        $rep_message = "some thank you message to " . $full_name;
        $message = 'another message which references ' . $subscribe;
        $reply = 'some message consisting of ' . $full_name;
        mail($admin_email,"Feedback",$message,$headers,"-fforwardguy@gmail.com");
        mail($feedback_email,"Feedback",$reply,$headers);
        }       
?>
```

[Edit] The Problem is that the form is only acknowledged as having been sent, but no data is received along with it.

[After edit extra info - Could the following things be affecting the form submission?
`

1. There are **2 forms** on the page in question.
2. Both forms are submitted via `AJAX`.
3. The first form functions **as expected**.
4. Two mail functions are being used in this single PHP file (handling only **one form**).
5. After taking taking a closer look - I have found that the email which gets sent contains **none of the text** entered into the form.

(The `AJAX` function works and the success functions are run.)

Comment: Are you sure your method is POST?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST['subscribed']);` and see what it says

Comment: The code is fine. I have checked locally. It should work if the form method is post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$subscribe = 'Would ' . (isset($_POST['subscribed']) && $_POST['subscribed'] == 'sub_me' ? 'like to ' : 'not like to ') . 'receive news emails.';`

Here I am checking if the `$_POST` variable is actually set and then we are doing a loose comparison check to see if `sub_me` is the submitted value.

You could also try leaving the `value` attribute blank on the form element, then just check if `$_POST['subscribed']` is actually set by just using `isset($_POST['subscribed'])`. If the checkbox is NOT checked, `isset($_POST['subscribed'])` will return `false`.

Comment: Care to explain the reason behind the down vote? A down vote without explanation is useless.

Comment: I think this answer might have worked in the first case (When the rest of the form seemed to be working). I don't know who downvoted you, though. I can't up/down vote people publicly yet - otherwise I would have equalised your answer for you.

Comment: @user2850190 I appreciate the consideration. If you remember when you're able, feel free to do so ;)

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I think I've equalized the score for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - so after I noticed what the actual problem was - I found out that My `AJAX` function was collecting data from the wrong form.